# Ratio of the expectation over the joint distribution and the expectation over the marginal distribution

Tags: probability, statistics, probability-distributions, conditional-expectation, expected-value

I have the following expression and I am having trouble understanding it

$$\frac{\int y f_{Y,X}(y,x) dy}{\int y f_Y(y) dy}$$

Where $f_{Y,X}(y,x)$ is the joint density function of random variables $X$ and $Y$  and $f_Y(y)$ the marginal density function of $Y$. For example if $Y$ is income and $X$ is some characteristic, I think this expression can be interpreted as the share of income (over total income) of the population with characteristic $X=x$. My reasoning comes from understanding that in the expression

$$\mathbb{E}(Y|X=x) = \frac{1}{f_X(x)}\int y f_{Y,X}(y,x) dy$$

$f_X(x)$ is the mass of people with characteristic $X=x$ and $\int y f_{Y,X}(y,x) dy$ is the sum (integral) of their incomes. In the case of $\int y f_Y(y) dy$ we are dividing by $1$ since the mass of the total population is one. Also, with discrete random variables it seems to make sense.

What makes me suspicious is the following example. Suppose $X_1 \sim U[0,1]$, $X_2 \sim U[0,1]$ and $Y = b_1 X_1 + b_2 X_2$. Let also $\mu = \int y f_Y(y) dy$. Also $f_{X_2}(X_2)$ is the pdf of $X_2$. Note

$$\frac{1}{\mu}\int y f_{Y,X_2}(y,X_2) dy = \frac{\mathbb{E}(Y|X_2)f_{X_2}(X_2)}{\mu} = \frac{\frac{b_1 + 2b_2 X_2}{2}}{\frac{b_1 + b_2}{2}}\mathbb{I}(0 \leq X_2 \leq 1) = \frac{b_1 + 2b_2 X_2}{b_1 + b_2}\mathbb{I}(0 \leq X_2 \leq 1)$$

Which is not necessarilly between zero and one ($X_2=1$ for example). So is my interpretation wrong? Or im I missing something in the example? If the interpretation is wrong is there a similar expression which can be interpreted as a share?

Comment: What exactly you want to calculate? $\mathbb E(...)$

Comment: Do not want to calculate anything. Just to know whether that ratio of expectations is a ratio of the weighted sum of Y for those with a given X over the weighted sum of Y in the total population. For instance if X is binary, 
$$
\frac{\frac{n_1}{n}\frac{1}{n_1}\sum_i Y_{1i}}{\frac{1}{n}\sum_i Y_i}
$$
Is the share of Y that belongs to group 1, where $n_1$ is the number of people in group 1 and $n$ is the total number of people. The question deals with continuous random variables but I though the reasoning should be the same as this one. But then there is something wrong with the example.

Comment: I´m really wondering that you say that you don't want to calculate something specific. My question is: What is your intention to calculate $\frac{1}{\mu}\int y f(y,X_2) dy =...$? What kind of expectation is it in your opinion?

Comment: It appears in an estimation im doing. Was thinking of estimating it like this
$$
\frac{\hat{\mathbb{E}}(Y|X_2)\hat{f}(X_2)}{\hat{\mu}}
$$
However in the question there is an analytical example. If it is correctly calculated I guess the ratio is not a share. Would like to know why my intuition of it being a share is wrong though.

Comment: What is not clear to me  is whether $f(y,x)$ is supposed to be a joint density or a conditional density or something else

Comment: oh sorry, yes. Should have made that clear, gonna edit it now. f(y,x) is a joint density function.